# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a array of object inside double quotes when i tried to parse
to array it is getting an error as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

```
var test = "[{'key' :'D', 'value': 'Deceased Date'},{'key' :'R', 'value': 'Retired Date'},{'key' :'T', 'value': 'Terminated Date'}]";
JSON.parse(test);
```

I've tried with this below code too.

```
$.parseJSON(test);
```

Comment: Swap `'` and `''`quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***No single quotes in JSON for a string.*** You should be doing this instead:

```
var test = '[{"key" :"D", "value": "Deceased Date"},{"key" :"R", "value": "Retired Date"},{"key" :"T", "value": "Terminated Date"}]';
JSON.parse(test);
```

In JSON only double quotes are valid.

You can find the standard on [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

> A value can be a string in ***double quotes***, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

In other words, no strings in single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Single quote doesn't make a valid json string. They should be wrapped within double quotes:

```
var test = '[{"key" :"D", "value": "Deceased Date"},{"key" :"R", "value": "Retired Date"},{"key" :"T", "value": "Terminated Date"}]';
JSON.parse(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey fairly simple fix.

No quotations around your array its just var x = [stuff in array]
It's already an object you don't need to parse it to json. 
To view it simply loop through your array.

```
var test = [
        {'key' :'D', 'value': 'Deceased Date'},
        {'key' :'R', 'value': 'Retired Date'},
        {'key' :'T', 'value': 'Terminated Date'}
      ];

 for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  console.log(test[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (in case you cannot change the test string, if it is coming from external source)

```
var test = "[{'key' :'D', 'value': 'Deceased Date'},{'key' :'R', 'value': 'Retired Date'},{'key' :'T', 'value': 'Terminated Date'}]".split('\'').join('\"');
JSON.parse(test);
```

just add this at the end of test `.split('\'').join('\"');` to replace `'` with `"`

or to make it more simple

```
var test = "[{'key' :'D', 'value': 'Deceased Date'},{'key' :'R', 'value': 'Retired Date'},{'key' :'T', 'value': 'Terminated Date'}]";
test = test..split('\'').join('\"');
    JSON.parse(test);
```